# What is DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dbtype

> An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "COMMENTS" column. The binding status was "DT_TEXT". The data flow column type is "DBBINDSTATUS_UNSUPPORTEDCONVERSION". The conversion from the OLE DB type of "DBTYPE_IUNKNOWN" to the destination column type of "DBTYPE_VARCHAR" might not be supported by this provider.

I have the above error when loading in a txt file. The `COMMENTS` field is `VARCHAR(4000)` the file is column pipe delimited with a text qualifier of `""`.

I'm stumped as cannot seem to find anything wrong with the data in the file itself, could this be a character somewhere that's not recognised??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Access to SQL. Binding error: The binding status was "DT\_NTEXT"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929438/ssis-access-to-sql-binding-error-the-binding-status-was-dt-ntext)

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9c30b104-77f4-4949-8379-fec57452ffb8/dbbindstatusunsupportedconversion-what-is-this?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Very odd indeed, I had set up a loader which data type Varchar (2000). This worked OK last time, but this time it didn't and only when I changed the data type to Text did the loader work. After more investigation I found that where ever there was a field with a field length of more than 255 the software we are using errored as originally posted. I will go back to the company we use and ask if something has changed in a recent upgrade as was fine before and now isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It went away after I changed the field size from VARCHAR(4000) to VARCHAR(max). Of course, you have to use the data conversion tool to change data type to text-stream(DT_TEXT).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the target column in the database via SSMS to nvarchar(max) then re-running the data flow worked for me.