# [Excel Destination [28]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a binding for the column. The binding status was "DT_NTEXT"

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm working on ssis package which exports data from SQL Server to Excel. I had a problem converting non-unicode to unicode string data types. So I created a derived Column task and converted to Unicode string [DT_WSTR] 4 columns which have a type Varchar(40) in SQL Server table. It worked with these columns. But I also have a Description column of type varchar(max) and I tried to convert it to Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]. It did not work.

Comment: What is the source data type in OLEDB ?

Comment: Why do u need a derived column, u can simply append a  data conversion task

Comment: I think this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929438/ssis-access-to-sql-binding-error-the-binding-status-was-dt-ntext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source is SQL Server (as you said), you can convert it directly in your SQL Query

```
SELECT 
     CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), 'att1')
    ,CONVERT(NTEXT, 'att2')
```

Convert your VARCHAR into **NVARCHAR**
Convert your TEXT into **NTEXT**

it's faster.

P.S. To test it (Do not forget to delete or reset your previous OLE DB Input component) -> It will be forced to reevaluate your datatype

Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked was to cast a Description column in Stored Procedure as varchar(1000). I checked the max length of this field and it was about 300 characters. So I made it varchar(1000) and in Derived column Unicode string [DT_WSTR]. This was a workaround, but I still want to know how to make it in ssis package without converting data type in Stored Procedure.